# Merge-sort algorithm throws "list index out of range" for big numbers

Tags: python, list, algorithm, merge

First of all, I will start by saying that I'm learning python at the moment.
I'm trying to understand the merge-sort by building the program myself. So far, I've done a function that merge two list. The problem is that this function works just fine for small numbers(like 1-70 or something like this) but if I want to go crazy throwing a number like 100 it will throw me a "list index out of range" error

```
def GenerateArray(n):
    randomlist=[]
    for i in range(0,n):
        n = random.randint(-100,100)
        randomlist.append(n)
    return randomlist

def Merge(a,b):
    c = list()
    i, j, k = 0, 0, 0
    longestList = max(len(a), len(b))
    if len(a) > len(b):
        while i < longestList:
            if a[i] == b[j]:
                c.append(a[i])
                i = i + 1
                j = j + 1
            elif j == len(b) - 1:
                i = i + 1
                j = 0
            else:
                j = j + 1
    else:
        while j <= longestList:
            if b[j] == a[i]:
                c.append(a[i])
                i = i + 1
                j = j + 1
            elif i == len(a) - 1:
                j = j + 1
                i = 0
            else:
                i = i + 1
    uniques = []
    for i in c:
        if i not in uniques:
            uniques.append(i)
    c = uniques
    print(c)


n=int(input("\nHow many items would you like your first array to have? "))
a=GenerateArray(n)
print("The first array is: ")
print(a)
n=int(input("\nHow many items would you like your second array to have? "))
b=GenerateArray(n)
print("The second array is: ")
print(b)
print("Merging the arrays...")
Merge(a,b)
```

Comment: I get the same error even with `n = 10`. It happens because you increment both `i` and `j` without checking if they're in the allowable range. Instead of incrementing, you can do `i = max(i + 1, len(a) - 1)` and `j = max(j + 1, len(b) - 1)`

Comment: Sorry, it looks like i forgot to change something on my to trying to figure out a solution.
In the  merge function, for the IF branch the first condition is 
while i <= longestList:
and on the else branch the condition is
while j < longestList:
This way it wont throw the error for n=10 or similar values.

Comment: `while j < longestList` still doesn't help you fix the problem of `i` being incremented beyond `len(a) - 1`. Similarly, `i < longestList` doesn't catch the problem of `j` being incremented beyond the valid limit.

Comment: Also, it looks like your solution worked for me, thank you very much!

Comment: Tried more combinations and it looks like I'm dealing with the same error for the combination n,n=6,10

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm tired, i keep forgetting things. Done the modifications through the whole algorithm, it looks like no problem is thrown anymore but the algorithm it's not doing it's job anymore. Maybe i did something wrong, can you post source code after the modification? Thank you and sorry for keep spamming you with replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you doing it in a very hard way? From what I can understand you are merging two lists and then you are printing out the unique numbers in them. You can do that in just a few lines of code.

```
c = a + b
unique = []
for i in c:
    if c.count(i) == 1:
        unique.append(i)
print(unique)
```

I am sorry if I have misunderstood the purpose of this program.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thank you for this comment, it looks like I really have a thing for overcomplicating things.
Have a great day and thank you again!

Comment: No problem. I wish you the same.